# how to recover deleted amadmin entry from opendj

Tags: openam

Accidently deleted the amadmin user entry present in dn --- u=users,ou=default,ou=GlobalConfig,ou=1.0,ou=sunIdentityRepositoryService,ou=services,dc=woodmac,dc=com.

Is there's any way recover the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only way is to re-create the entries using 'ldapmodify'.

You have to use 'ampassword' utility from 'ssoadmintools' to encrypt the password to put it into the entry.